# SSD: What are the differences among Gen 3.0, 3.0 x4 and Gen 4.0?

Tags: linux, pc, hard-disk, ssd, performance

For a PC Desktop to be buy it in these weeks, there are the following SSD options:

```
SSD HP EX950, 512GB, M.2, 2280, PCIe Gen 3x4, NVMe 1.3.
SSD HP EX950, 1TB, M.2, 2280, PCIe Gen 3.0 x4, NVMe 1.3.
SSD Samsung 970 EVO PLUS, 250GB, M.2, PCIe 3.0 x4, NVMe 1.3
SSD Samsung 980 PRO 1TB SSD M.2 2280, PCIe Gen 4.0 NVMe 1.3c
SSD Samsung 980 PRO 2TB SSD M.2 2280, PCIe Gen 4.0 NVMe 1.3c
```

To do the correct choice, I want to know

- What are the differences among Gen 3.0, 3.0 x4 and Gen 4.0?

**Note** just in case - the PC Desktop is going to be used for Development and Server purposes with `Ubuntu` - is not going to be included other OS directly in the same PC. But yes other OS through Virtual Box is going to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://insights.samsung.com/2021/10/07/pcie-4-0-vs-pcie-3-0-whats-the-difference/

The *Gen* as in generation refers to PCIe 3.0 and PCIe 4.0.

4.0 has double the performance of 3.0, you can look all that up on google.  The key point is whether you're motherboard supports PCIe 4.0 or not,  PCIe was released in 2017 but nothing pcie 4.0 came to market for a while.  It's been a while since I looked into it, but that's what you want to look in to.

The x4 reference is the pcie lanes that the m.2 ssd is using; there's x1, x4, x8, x16.  graphics cards use either x8 or x16.  The amount of pcie lanes that an ssd uses I believe is x4... they throw that `x4` into the ssd marketing to wow buyers, because, x4 just sounds b@d@ass added on with all that other technical jibber jabber.  I don't think m.2 ssd, because of the size of it can do more than x4 you would need more pins and a full size pcie slot that is now a few inches long as opposed to about 1 inch.

more reading:

https://www.trentonsystems.com/blog/pcie-gen-4-reference-guide

https://www.makeuseof.com/best-budget-pcie-4-motherboards/

https://www.cgdirector.com/guide-to-pcie-lanes/

**be aware there are 2 kinds of m.2 ssd's.   NVMe and SATA m2.ssd.  So be sure to get the correct one for your motherboard, many support SATA m.2 ssd and only the higher end motherboards and servers offer m.2 nvme ssd.**

https://www.backblaze.com/blog/nvme-vs-m-2-drives/